# The consecutive days counter for Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow are different

Tags: support, consecutive-days

I login to Stack Overflow and after some time, say 5 to 6 minutes later, I login to Meta. The consecutive days count for the main site increments, but for Meta is not, and resets. Why does it reset even after I visit the site? Am I missing something?

Comment: They are separate sites... You have to visit each one separately each day...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your visit to count you must *do something*, just logging in to the site, Main or Meta, doesn't count. Try voting on a few questions, editing, commenting or better yet, answering.

Comment: _asdfg_ woo-hoo this day counts as MSO visit to me! gotta go, I've got a few more sites to mark as visited

Comment: @gnat If you are going to do that, there's a nifty script that'll give you Fanatic on all sites, do that instead...